# ssh через QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, ssh

Есть вот такой код :

```
QProcess* proc = new QProcess();  
proc->start("cmd.exe");
proc->write("ssh\n");
proc->closeWriteChannel();
proc->waitForFinished();
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 866");
ui->textEditNormal->setText(codec->toUnicode(proc->readAllStandardOutput()));
ui->textEditError->setText(codec->toUnicode(proc->readAllStandardError()));
```

В `StandardError` выдает :

```
"ssh" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Если повторяю все через консоль,то все нормально.

Как это исправить?

Comment: А полный путь Вы не пробовали указывать?

Comment: `proc->write("C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe\n");` Пишет : `Системе не удается найти указанный путь`

Comment: в самой cmd вы когда просто пишите ssh, вызывается ssh?

Comment: В самой консоли `cmd` когда пишу `ssh` вызывается подсказка по ключам: `usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           destination [command]`

Comment: А вот так тоже не работает: start(“cmd.exe”, QStringList() << “/C” << “path to ssh”) ?

Comment: @isnullxbh а как проверить работоспособность?Мне нужно подключится к виртуалке по ssh,и там уже выполнять команды.Т.е нужно в идеале через `write` иметь полноценное общение с ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась.дело в том что `QProcess` вызывает `cmd.exe` из `SysWOW64`.Но по какой то причине(возможно из-за нехватки прав) он не видит `ssh.exe` внутри `system32`.Поэтому я вытащил `ssh.exe` из `system32` в не папку `Windows`(ну и конечно с указанием абсолютного пути).Все работает.